# Terraform error : │ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name

Tags: terraform, fusionauth

I am trying to use terraform template but getting the following error because of the tricky value in the variable

```
resource "fusionauth_email" "verification_template" {
  name                  =  "${local.email_verification_template_name} [${var.env_name}]"
  localized_subjects = {
    "ar" = "${local.email_verification_localized_subjects} [${var.env_name}]"
  }
  localized_html_templates = {
    "ar" = templatefile("${path.module}/email-templates/email-passwordless.ar.html.tmpl", { url = var.url })
  }
}
```

However when I try to use the value in the actual module it gives me error.

```
module "fusionauth_sit" {
  source           = "../modules/fusionauth"
  env_name            = "Test"
  tenant_host         = "test"
  url                 = "https://nonprod.com/auth/prod/${code}"
 }
```

Because of the ${code} it gives me error

Template file :

```
[#setting url_escaping_charset="UTF-8"]
[#assign url = "${url}" /]

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link
```

How to resolve this error

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question, but '${}' is significant to Terraform, so is it a case of escaping (e.g. '$${}' ) - https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/strings.html#escape-sequences

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: @mooreds: │ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.

Comment: @clockworknet: that resolved the error but my template file contains content like ````${user.data.nickname}``` which gives me error ``` vars map does not contain key "user", referenced at ../modules/fusionauth/email-templates/email-passwordles``` how to resolve that?

Comment: What is `code`? You haven't defined such a variable, local or a resource.